# Lwip UDP and UART

Tags: udp, uart, lwip, asf

LWIP library version - 2.1.2
Atmel Studio - version 7.0
Demo code - THIRDPARTY_LWIP_RAW_BASIC_HTTP_EXAMPLE
Target device - ATSAME70Q21
Dev Board - ATSAME70- Xplained
Compiler - GCC

We are trying to send/receive data to the controller through Uart and UDP.

In the mainloop, we are sending udp data to the PC by calling ass_udp_send().

And we are sending data from PC to controller through UART.

Issue - PC receives the UDP data sent by the controller. Once the PC sents data through UART, PC stops receiving the udp data sent by controller.
Control reaching ass_udp_send() function but data is not received on PC side.

Please refer the below google drive link for project code.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RW4bjnJE-VGNixhZyfXcm3aYEWr6oeID?usp=sharing